# Why is dative used here?

Tags: grammar-identification

I have come across this sentence, and do not really understand why the dative is being used in the second clause. Could somebody explain why?

> Tipps für den Besuch in Schwäbisch Gmünd - einer süddeutschen Kleinstadt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case of *einer süddeutschen Kleinstadt* is the same as that of *Schwäbisch Gmünd*, it is just that for the name you cannot tell as clearly that it is dative. You are probably aware that *in* takes accusative or dative depending on (as a rule of thumb) whether it describes a movement or not. Here it is perceived as being *in* and not *into*. So it is

> eine Fahrt in eine süddeutsche Kleinstadt

but

> ein Besuch in einer süddeutschen Kleinstadt.